# Counting lines and triangles determined by ten points in the plane

Tags: discrete-mathematics, permutations, combinations

> Ten points labeled A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J are arranged in a plane in such a way that no three lie on the same straight line.
>
> a) How many straight lines are determined by the ten points? 
>   45
>
> **b)How many of these straight lines do not pass through point A? 
>   9**
>
> c) How many triangles have three of the ten points as vertices? 
>   120
>
> d) How many of these triangles do not have A as a vertex? 
>   84

I can't able to solve the b) part. Can anyone tell me why my answer is still wrong, such I was doing with $_9C_1 = 9$ (wrong answer).

Answer (score 3):

In part (b), nine of the lines pass through $A$. The other $\binom{9}{2}-9=\binom{8}{2}=\boxed{36}$ lines don't pass through $A$. **That** is the right answer.

Comment: Yes, thanks this is the right answer.